# Python Flask to change text in a HTML file

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to create a simple program which will replace {{ test }} with 'Hello world' by following a tutorial, however I am stumped and when I open the HTML file - as {{ test }} is shown on the page instead of 'Hello World' which is what should be appearing.

Any help would be appreciated because I am very unsure on what to do to fix this, thanks.

I am unsure if I have even linked the two files, as to my knowledge it was never specified in the video and I have only just noticed that there is no link between the two files.

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html', test='hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    homepage()
else:
    print('Please run this file as main, not as module.')
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<p> {{ test }} </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask is a webserver. You are not meant to call the functions with `app.route`. Replace the last part with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and then visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in your browser. The template file is not meant to change.

If for some reason you don't want to run a server but you just want to create HTML files, then use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/#basic-api-usage), the template engine behind Flask.